# How can I extract a number from string using regex with various formats (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, json, regex

I have a MySQL data table which stores metadata for client transactions. I am writing a query to extract a number out of the metadata column, which is essentially a JSON stored as a string.

I am trying to find 'clients' and extract the first number after clients. The data can be stored in several different ways; see the examples below:

- `..."type\":\"temp\",\"typeOther\":\"\",\"clients\":\"2\",\"hours\":\"5\",\...`
- `..."id\":31457,\"clients\":2,\"cancel\":false\...`

I've tried the following Regexp:

- `(?<=clients.....)[0-9]+`
- `(?<=clients...)[0-9]*(?=[[^:digit:]])`

And I've tried the following json_extract, but it returned a null value:

- `json_extract(rd.meta, '$.clients')`

The regexp functions do work, **but** the first one only works on the first example, while the second only works on the second example.

What regexp should I use such that it's dynamic and will pull the number nested between two non-word char sets after 'clients'?

Comment: You mention using `json_extract()` but you don't say whether that worked. Did it? That would be easier, more efficient, and less prone to breaking than either of the regular expression solutions. Why do you want to use a regular expression instead of the existing MySQL builtin function?

Comment: Apologies Bill. The json_extract() did not work. It returned null.

Comment: That could happen if your text isn't valid JSON. For instance, if you forgot a comma or those backslashes are really part of the text (are they?). You don't show a full example of your JSON.

Comment: If you're not storing the data in a column defined as MySQL's [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), why aren't you? It would ensure that the JSON is formed correctly — it would reject any invalid JSON data.

Comment: Yes, the backslashes are in the text. I'm not the sysadmin, but I did confirm using dBeaver that the data type is JSON.

Comment: Oh my. So it's worse than I thought. Technically a JSON document can be a single double-quoted string. But the content of that string in your case is itself a fragment of JSON, with the embedded double-quotes escaped with backslashes. I think you need to have a conversation with your sysadmin and perhaps more broadly about how they got into this state and how they intend anyone to query that data.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely have a chat with them. Is there a potential regex solution I can use as a stopgap? Despite the inefficiencies that come along with regex, I'm wiling to take that on the chin to get the data in the meantime.

Comment: You could make a script, read the JSON stored as a string, rebuild it and save it in a new JSON data type column.

Answer (score 0):

```
clients.*?([0-9]+)
^^^^^^^            -- exact match
       ^^^         -- non-greedy string of anything
          ^      ^ -- capture
           ^^^^^^  -- string of 1 or more digits (greedy)
```

Comment: Does MySQL support the `*?` non-greedy wildcard syntax? It doesn't as far as I know. It substantially less fancy the full-blown PCRE syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I did this test on MySQL 8.0.29, but it should work on MySQL 5.x too:

```
mysql> set @s1 = '..."type\":\"temp\",\"typeOther\":\"\",\"clients\":\"2\",\"hours\":\"5\",\...';

mysql> set @s2 = '..."id\\":31457,\\"clients\\":2,\\"cancel\\":false\\...';

mysql> select trim(leading '\\"' from substring_index(@s1, '\\"clients\\":', -1)) as clients;
+--------------------------+
| clients                  |
+--------------------------+
| 2\",\"hours\":\"5\",\... |
+--------------------------+

mysql> select trim(leading '\\"' from substring_index(@s2, '\\"clients\\":', -1)) as clients;
+------------------------+
| clients                |
+------------------------+
| 2,\"cancel\":false\... |
+------------------------+
```

Then cast the result as an integer to get rid of the non-numeric part following the number.

```
mysql> select cast(trim(leading '\\"' from substring_index(@s1, '\\"clients\\":', -1)) as unsigned) as clients;
+---------+
| clients |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+

mysql> select cast(trim(leading '\\"' from substring_index(@s2, '\\"clients\\":', -1)) as unsigned) as clients;
+---------+
| clients |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+
```